# How to fix codeigniter pagination and route

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, uri, routes

I have problem whit codeignitet pagination and route!
I set the route my function class like this:

```
$route['admin/panel/students/new-stuedents-list/:num'] = "admin/newStuedentsList/$1";
```

then in my controller, I create a function that call  `newStuedentsList` and load pagination library, every things work fine but pagination nav... :( 
the page loaded successfully...
and the data is correct...
bat when I click for example page 2 , the page 2 loaded successfully but the pagination nav show page i button ...! 
when I call page 4 form url (http:// localhost/d/index.php/admin/panel/students/new-stuedents-list/30) , again the data is correctly ... but the pagination nav show page 1 button and the number of page don't change!

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/d/index.php/admin/panel/students/new-stuedents-list/';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('new_contest')->num_rows();
$config['pre_page'] = 10;
$config['num_links'] = 20;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$adminInfo = $this->admin_model->adminInfo();
$newStudentsList['students'] = $this->admin_model->newStudentsList($config['pre_page'],$this->uri->segment(5));

$data = array_merge($adminInfo,$newStudentsList);
$this->load->view('admin/newStudentsList',$data);
```

but when the `newStuedentsList` is:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/d/index.php/admin/newStuedentsList/';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('new_contest')->num_rows();
$config['pre_page'] = 10;
$config['num_links'] = 20;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$adminInfo = $this->admin_model->adminInfo();
$newStudentsList['students'] = $this->admin_model->newStudentsList($config['pre_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

$data = array_merge($adminInfo,$newStudentsList);
$this->load->view('admin/newStudentsList',$data);
```

every things work fine!
How do I fix this problem ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot one configuration:

`$config['uri_segment'] = 5;`

To determines which segment of your URI contains the page number.

And replace `pre_page` by `per_page`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for your useful answer.